# I want to choose different element in each loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I want to choose different element of array in each loop. For example, in the code below array and loop counts are not equal to length of array. But I must choose some elements in the main loop and then I will append my choices to new array.

```
   e1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
      c=0
      e2=[]
   while c<=3:
      c+=1
      for i in e1:
          e2.append(i)

    print(e2)
```

.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

But I want to choose 1 in first loop, 2 in second loop and 3 in third loop. So new array must be [1, 2, 3]. But every element of array is generated automatically.

Comment: use `while c<3:
      
      
          e2.append(e1[c]) c+=1`

Comment: What is your expected output? Could you [edit] the question and include it.

Comment: Why do you even need a loop for this?

Comment: BTW, that's not an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list).

Answer (score 1):

```
e1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
e2=[]
c=0
while c<3:
    e2.append(e1[c])
    c+=1
print(e2)
```

output

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, [] are called lists.

When you are writing `for i in e1`, it iterates over every element in the list `e1`, and then `e2.append(i)` appends every one of this `i` into the new list `e2`. Effectively the statement `while c<=3:` makes sure you do this (append every item of e1 to e2 for three times) which is not what you want. @prashant's comment would be one way to do what you want.
A more pythonic way would be, unless I am mistaken about what you want:

```
e1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
c=0
e2=[]
for i in e1[:3]:
    e2.append(i)
print(e2)
```

Every item in a list can be accessed as `list[item_index]` i.e. `e1[0] is 1`, `e1[3] is 4`, etc. And lists can be 'sliced' as `list[start_index:end_index+1]` i.e. `e1[0:3] gives [1,2,3]` i.e. `e1[0], e1[1], e1[2]`